# Is there an iCloud equivalent to Google's Inactive Account Manager?

Tags: icloud, user-account

Google has an [Inactive Account Manager](https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/inactive) that allows you to specify people who will be given access to your account if you do not log in after a set amount of time. For instance, I have it set up so that if I don't log in after 3 months, then my family will be given read-only access to my account. Additionally, I can choose to delete my account outright.

Is there an equivalent feature for iCloud? I'm especially interested in iCloud backups. Can I set it so that if something were to happen to me, people of my choosing could gain access to it?

Answer (score 1):

iCloud has a feature called Legacy Contacts. If you name someone as a Legacy Contact, then they can submit to Apple:

- An access key - either printed out or saved to their Apple ID data
- Your death certificate

They will have 3 years of account access, after which your account is permanently erased.

Read more at Apple.com:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212360